# directx transformedcolored color field alpha value

Tags: c#, colors, directx, alpha

I am using C #. I need to draw points using DirectX and they should be semitransparent. I declared vertices to be transformedColored and set the color value to be:

```
 vertices[i].Color = Color.FromArgb(20,0,0,255).ToArgb();
```

This should be quite transparent blue but what I got was opaque blue. Whatever value I use for the alpha value, it always gets fully opaque.
Any ideas why? I hope the  transformedcolored color field supports alpha value.

Thanks in advance.

The drawing code is:

```
device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, System.Drawing.Color.White, 1.0f, 0);

device.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;

device.RenderState.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;

device.RenderState.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.InvSourceAlpha;

device.RenderState.BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;

CustomVertex.TransformedColored[] vertices = new CustomVertex.TransformedColored[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   vertices[i].Position = new Vector4(2.5f + (g_embed[i, 0] - minx) * (width - 5.0f) / maxx, 2.5f + (g_embed[i, 1] - miny) * (height - 5.0f) / maxy, 0f, 1f);//g_embed, minx, width,maxx, miny,height, maxy are all predifined

   vertices[i].Color = Color.FromArgb(20, 0, 0, 255).ToArgb();
}

 device.BeginScene();

 device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.TransformedColored.Format;

 device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.PointList, N, vertices);

 device.EndScene();

 device.Present();

 this.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Did you activated alphablending and adjusted the related renderstates?

Comment: i added these: device.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
            device.RenderState.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One;
            device.RenderState.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.One;
            device.RenderState.BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;

Comment: Which framework do you use? XNA 3?

Comment: I am using C# Directx 11.

Comment: Hmm, whats about your shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your renderstates are used for premultiplied alpha. Using a real alpha-channel needs the following settings ([Blendenumerationdoc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.blend%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)):

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.SourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha;
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.BlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add;
```

It creates following the formular, where a is your alpha of the color: a * SourceColor + (1-a) * DestColor

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it is still not working.. I am using the setting exactly as you posted and then for the vertices, I used vertices[i].Color = Color.FromArgb(20,0,0,255).ToArgb(); But I still get full opacity. I am kinda confused about the destination color, is it something I need to set? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, what a pity :) Can you show your drawing code? Maybe additional your vertices + declaration can be interesting.

Comment: The destination color is the color of the destination surface, where you render to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply again. I added my drawing code in the original post. I think I might be making some stupid mistakes in there..